# expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token when I have using ::va_list;

Tags: c++

I am including cstdarg and get the following error:

> expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘{’ token"

The error occurs on the following line:

```
  using ::va_list;
```

Here is the content of cstdarg:

```
#pragma GCC system_header

#include </usr/include/c++/4.6.3/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h>

#include <stdarg.h>

#ifndef _GLIBCXX_CSTDARG

#define _GLIBCXX_CSTDARG 1

// Adhere to section 17.4.1.2 clause 5 of ISO 14882:1998

#ifndef va_end
#define va_end(ap) va_end (ap)
#endif

namespace std

{

  using ::va_list;     I get the error here!

} // namespace std

#endif
```

and va_list was called in this file :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include </usr/include/c++/4.6.3/tr1/stdarg.h>


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include </usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h>


#include "string.h"

#include "libnitro.h"
#include "nitro.h"

#define KVM_NODE "/dev/kvm"

int kvm_fd;
int kvm_vmfd;
struct nitro_vcpus vcpus;

 int kvm_ioctl(int type, ...)
{  
int ret;
void *arg;
va_list ap;

va_start(ap, type);
arg = va_arg(ap, void *);
va_end(ap);

ret = ioctl(kvm_fd, type, arg);
if (ret == -1)
    ret = -errno;

return ret;
}

  int kvm_vm_ioctl(int type, ...)
 {
 int ret;
 void *arg;
 va_list ap;

va_start(ap, type);
arg = va_arg(ap, void *);
va_end(ap);

ret = ioctl(kvm_vmfd, type, arg);
if (ret == -1)
    ret = -errno;

return ret;
 }

 int kvm_vcpu_ioctl(int vcpu_fd,int type, ...){
 int ret;`
 `  void *arg;`
 `  va_list ap;`

  va_start(ap, type);
arg = va_arg(ap, void *);
va_end(ap);

ret = ioctl(vcpu_fd, type, arg);
if (ret == -1)
    ret = -errno;

return ret;
}




int kvm_ioctl(int type, ...)
{

  int ret;

  void *arg;

  va_list ap;

  va_start(ap, type);
  arg = va_arg(ap, void *);
  va_end(ap);

  ret = ioctl(kvm_fd, type, arg);
  if (ret == -1)
    ret = -errno;

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. I'd bet very highly it's not the header's fault.

Comment: I am working on a code that has included stdarg.h, then cstdargh is included inside stdarg.h and when I go inside it gives me this error:    make nitro 
gcc -c -o libnitro.o libnitro.c -g -Wall
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6.3/tr1/stdarg.h:32:0,
                 from libnitro.c:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.6.3/cstdarg:55:1: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’
/usr/include/c++/4.6.3/cstdarg:56:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
make: *** [libnitro.o] Error 1

Comment: Please add information to the post rather than posting as a comment if it is useful additional information

Comment: What's the smallest file you can write and compile to get this error?

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be doing `using namespace std;` what you've done is declare that your code is in the std namespace

Comment: I [tried to reproduce it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66e79ad25b8bb41c) from the information given, but who knows what I did wrong. Also, `gcc` is the C compiler, not C++. I guess that could be a possible cause.

Comment: @chris: _Absolutely_, especially with a filename ending in `.c`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, [Unfortunately...](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ab1ad1b96750a9f)

Comment: @chris: It seems quite reasonable to me. I imagine it would be more than a little annoying if you were a C developer and everything you wrote got compiled as C++ for no reason!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Sorry, that's not what I meant. The sample still compiles with `gcc` and a `.c` extension on Coliru at least (and oh duh, I'm not even doing any C++-ish things, that's just the OP's stdarg.h including cstdarg and such).

Comment: @chris: Well, you posted a valid C program... :P (The OP did not) [Oh noes!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bdc7f09b78160f8)

Comment: @EdChum: No, that's a header in the standard library doing that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yeah, silly me. I was going from the comment that just said `stdarg.h`.

Answer (score 1):

You should compile your c++ code with `g++` not `gcc`.

Additionally, most users (and programs) expect that files that end in `.c`, (like `libnitro.c`) use the C language, not the C++ language. For c++ source code, you should name your file `libnitro.cpp` or `libnitro.cc`.

Comment: I am building the code in eclipse so how can I switch to g++ instead of gcc?

Comment: It _did_ help. It's just that you've done something else wrong as well.